Intel Ethernet Network Adapter E810 Inventory Data Query
I want to query the E810 NIC Card whether it containes GNSS Mezzanine card. Is there any command to query the GNSS module on it?
I have tried to get the related information by using "lshw" command, but it returned without any useful information.
Thanks, BR
Burhan
